# Why do C++ container and iterator requirements specify size_type and difference_type as integer types?

Tags: c++, types, iterator, containers, language-lawyer

The [[container.requirements]](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements) specify that for a *Container* type *X*, `X::difference_type` and `X::size_type` are signed and unsigned **integer types** (defined by [[basic.fundamental]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#def:unsigned_integer_type)). The same goes for iterators' *difference type*.

**What are the reasons that these are not allowed to be an enumeration type or any object type?**

*Edit:* Of course the types above should satisfy some necessary requirements, e.g., support some arithmetic operations. I don't expect `X::size_type` defined to be `struct Empty {};` with no operators to work.

My motivation is that I want to define `X::size_type` and `X::difference_type` as user-defined types whose defined operators form an affine space and therefore differ from operators defined for builtin integer types. (Affine spaces would mean that I only define operations that make mathematical sense for the types and mitigate common bugs, [see an example here](http://videocortex.io/2018/Affine-Space-Types/).)

> Note: this question is *not* about signed versus unsigned. I know about this: [Is using an unsigned rather than signed int more likely to cause bugs? Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51677855/is-using-an-unsigned-rather-than-signed-int-more-likely-to-cause-bugs-why)

One possible answer I can think of is that users might want to use types as non-type template parameters, but that could still work with enumeration types.

*Edit*: Another possible answer is perhaps that the "necessary requirements" in my edit above are simply not defined yet and it was easier to go with what already exists in the standard.

Comment: Are you writing an implementation of the C++ standard library?

Comment: That could be annoying if you want to use your iterator type to implement an allocator. Otherwise you don't have to worry about that. The requirement of the library is to put in relation to the fact that there exist whatsoever an integer type that is large enough to represent the difference of address of all available memory, so there is no need for something more evolved than an integer type.

Comment: Whatever your implementation would do, at the end the difference type would be, by nature of its semantic, something that would behave exactly like integer type, then why would you need something else?

Comment: @StoryTeller It would be interesting to see the results of such a change in libcxx or libstdc++ but otherwise no.

Comment: @Oliv Thanks, allocator requirement are another place where I would have the same issue.
@Jean-BaptisteYunès it would support a subset of operations supported by integer types. For example disable `diff_t * diff_t` but this is out of scope here.